# Dynamic Database Stored Procedure on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to build a stored procedure that will query multiple database depending on the databases required.

For example:

`SP_Users` takes a list of `@DATABASES` as parameters.

For each database it needs to run the same query and union the results together.

I believe a `CTE` could be my best bet so I have something like this at the moment.

```
SET @DATABASES = 'DB_1, DB_2'  -- Two databases in a string listed

-- I have a split string function that will extract each database
SET @CURRENT_DB = 'DB_1'

WITH UsersCTE (Name, Email)
AS (SELECT Name, Email 
    FROM [@CURRENT_DB].[dbo].Users),

    SELECT @DATABASE as DB, Name, Email
    FROM UsersCTE
```

What I don't want to do is hard code the databases in the query. The steps I image are:

1. Split the parameter `@DATABASES` to extract and set the `@CURRENT_DB` Variable
2. Iterate through the query with a Recursive CTE until all the `@DATABASES` have been processed
3. Union all results together and return the data.

Not sure if this is the right approach to tackling this problem.

Comment: You can't parameterize object or database names like this. The approach you are attempting is never going to work. It will require dynamic sql.

Comment: Have a look at Aaron Bertrand's Article [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/).

Comment: @SeanLange If It was a dynamic query how could that even work?

Comment: You would build a dynamic sql string that unions all the queries together and then you execute the dynamic string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the valid advice from others here and went with this which works great for what I need:

I decided to use a loop to build the query up. Hope this helps someone else looking to do something similar.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Users](
    @DATABASES VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @PARAM1 VARCHAR(250),
    @PARAM2 VARCHAR(250)
)

BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Local variables
    DECLARE 
     @COUNTER INT = 0,
     @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
     @CURRENTDB VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
     @MAX INT = 0,
     @ERRORMSG VARCHAR(MAX)

    --Check we have databases entered
    IF @DATABASES IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('ERROR: No Databases Provided, 
        Please Provide a list of databases to execute procedure. See stored procedure: 
        [SP_Users]', 16, 1) 
        RETURN 
    END

    -- SET Number of iterations based on number of returned databases
    SET @MAX = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
               (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.value) AS RowNumber,  i.value 
               FROM dbo.udf_SplitVariable(@DATABASES, ',') AS i)X)

    -- Build SQL Statement 
    WHILE @COUNTER < @MAX
        BEGIN

        --Set the current database
        SET @CURRENTDB = (SELECT X.Value FROM 
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.value) AS RowNumber,  i.value 
            FROM dbo.udf_SplitVariable(@DATABASES, ',') AS i
            ORDER BY RowNumber OFFSET @COUNTER
            ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) X);


        SET @SQL = @SQL + N'
                          (
                          SELECT Name, Email
                          FROM [' + @CURRENTDB + '].[dbo].Users
                          WHERE 
                              (Name = @PARAM1 OR @PARAM1 IS NULL)
                              (Email = @PARAM2 OR @PARAM2 IS NULL)
                          ) '
                          + N' UNION ALL '

            END
            PRINT @CURRENTDB
            PRINT @SQL

            SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
        END

        -- remove last N' UNION ALL '
        IF LEN(@SQL) > 11
            SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 11)

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@CURRENTDB VARCHAR(50), 
                                   @PARAM1 VARCHAR(250), 
                                   @PARAM2 VARCHAR(250)', 
                                   @CURRENTDB, 
                                   @PARAM1 , 
                                   @PARAM2


END
```

---

Split Variable Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_SplitVariable]
(
    @List varchar(8000),
    @SplitOn varchar(5) = ','
)

RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Value VARCHAR(8000)
)

AS
BEGIN

--Account for ticks
SET @List = (REPLACE(@List, '''', ''))

--Account for 'emptynull'
IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@List)) = 'emptynull'
BEGIN
    SET @List = ''
END

--Loop through all of the items in the string and add records for each item
WHILE (CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (value)
    SELECT Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, 1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @List)-1)))  

    SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@List) + LEN(@SplitOn), LEN(@List))

END

INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Value)
SELECT Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))

RETURN

END
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using @databases:

As mentioned in the comments to your question, variables cant be used to dynamically select a database.  Dynamic sql is indicated.  You can start by building your template sql statement:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
    'union all ' + 
    'select ''@db'' as db, name, email ' + 
    'from [@db].dbo.users ';
```

Since you have sql server 2016, you can split using the `string_split` function, with your `@databases` variable as input.  This will result in a table with 'value' as the column name, which holds the database names.

Use the `replace` function to replace `@db` in the template with `value`.  This will result in one sql statement for each database you passed into @databases.  Then, concatenate the statements back together.  Unfortunately, in version 2016, there's no built in function to do that.  So we have to use the famous `for xml` trick to join the statements, then we use `.value` to convert it to a string, and finally we use `stuff` to get rid of the leading `union all` statement.

Take the results of the concatenated output, and overwrite the `@sql` variable.  It is ready to go at this point, so execute it.

I do all that is described in this code:

```
declare @databases nvarchar(max) = 'db_1,db_2';

set @sql = stuff(
    (

        select      replace(@sql, '@db', value)
        from        string_split(@databases, ',')
        for xml     path(''), type

    ).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 9, '');

exec(@sql);
```

Untested, of course, but if you print instead of execute, it seems to give the proper sql statement for your needs.

#### Using msForEachDB:

Now, if you didn't want to have to know which databases had 'users', such as if you're in an environment where you have a different database for every client, you can use sp_msForEachDb and check the structure first to make sure it has a 'users' table with 'name' and 'email' columns.  If so, execute the appropriate statement.  If not, execute a dummy statement.  I won't describe this one, I'll just give the code:

```
declare @aggregator table (
    db sysname,
    name int,
    email nvarchar(255)
);

insert @aggregator
exec sp_msforeachdb '

    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''select db = '''''''', name = '''''''', email = '''''''' where 1 = 2'';

    select      @sql = ''select db = ''''?'''', name, email from ['' + table_catalog + ''].dbo.users''
    from        [?].information_schema.columns
    where       table_schema = ''dbo''
    and         table_name = ''users''
    and         column_name in (''name'', ''email'')
    group by    table_catalog
    having      count(*) = 2

    exec (@sql);

';


select      *
from        @aggregator
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @pwilcox I think for more complex queries it would be harder to run so I actually used my own method based on your suggestion